# Chrome net-logs CANCELLED event: possible cause?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, vaadin

I am debugging an incident while clients are using our website to download a report of `.csv` but never got the file. Button clicked and no file downloading happening.

It happens occasionally and it cannot be reproduced constantly. I suspect some firewall is playing around the downloading. But what could be wrong downloading a csv file?

Anyway, captured net log file of Chrome shows a `CANCELLED` event when failure:

```
14080: URL_REQUEST
https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv
Start Time: 2023-12-12 09:46:17.255

t=4087 [st=  0] +CORS_REQUEST  [dt=882]
                 --> cors_preflight_policy = "consider_preflight"
                 --> headers = "sec-ch-ua: \"Google Chrome\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24\"\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: \"Windows\"\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7\r\n\r\n"
                 --> is_revalidating = false
                 --> method = "GET"
                 --> url = "https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv"
t=4087 [st=  0]    CHECK_CORS_PREFLIGHT_REQUIRED
                   --> preflight_required = false
t=4087 [st=  0]   +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=882]
                   --> priority = "HIGHEST"
                   --> traffic_annotation = 63171670
                   --> url = "https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv"
t=4087 [st=  0]      NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_URL_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=4087 [st=  0]     +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=882]
                     --> initiator = "https://client.app.net"
                     --> load_flags = 131072 (CAN_USE_SHARED_DICTIONARY)
                     --> method = "GET"
                     --> network_isolation_key = "https://our.company.net https://our.company.net"
                     --> request_type = "subframe"
                     --> site_for_cookies = "SiteForCookies: {site=https://our.company.net; schemefully_same=true}"
                     --> url = "https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv"
t=4087 [st=  0]        FIRST_PARTY_SETS_METADATA  [dt=0]
                       --> cache_filter = "none"
                       --> frame_entry = "none"
                       --> top_frame_primary = "none"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COMPUTED_PRIVACY_MODE
                       --> privacy_mode = "disabled"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_DOMAIN_MISMATCH, EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_DOMAIN_MISMATCH, EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_DOMAIN_MISMATCH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=4087 [st=  0]        NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_START_TRANSACTION  [dt=0]
t=4087 [st=  0]        HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=4087 [st=  0]        HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_OR_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=1]
                       --> result = "created"
t=4088 [st=  1]        HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=4088 [st=  1]       +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=563]
t=4088 [st=  1]          HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                         --> source_dependency = 14086 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=4651 [st=564]          HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                         --> source_dependency = 14088 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=4651 [st=564]       -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=4651 [st=564]       +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_CONNECTED  [dt=0]
t=4651 [st=564]          PRIVATE_NETWORK_ACCESS_CHECK
                         --> client_address_space = "public"
                         --> resource_address_space = "public"
                         --> result = "allowed-potentially-trustworthy-same-origin"
t=4651 [st=564]       -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_CONNECTED
t=4651 [st=564]       +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=4652 [st=565]          HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                         --> GET /some/url/report.csv HTTP/1.1
                             Host: client.app.net
                             Connection: keep-alive
                             sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
                             sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
                             sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
                             Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
                             User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
                             Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
                             Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
                             Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
                             Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
                             Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
                             Referer: https://client.app.net/
                             Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                             Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8
                             Cookie: [505 bytes were stripped]
t=4652 [st=565]       -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=4652 [st=565]       +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=317]
t=4652 [st=565]          HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=317]
t=4969 [st=882] -CORS_REQUEST
t=4970 [st=883]  CANCELLED
t=4970 [st=883] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

While the normal download shows a correct 200 response after `HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS`.

```
938: URL_REQUEST
https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv
Start Time: 2023-12-12 11:02:46.569

t=8075 [st=  0] +CORS_REQUEST  [dt=851]
                 --> cors_preflight_policy = "consider_preflight"
                 --> headers = "sec-ch-ua: \"Not_A Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"120\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"120\"\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: \"Windows\"\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7\r\n\r\n"
                 --> is_revalidating = false
                 --> method = "GET"
                 --> url = "https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv"
t=8075 [st=  0]    CHECK_CORS_PREFLIGHT_REQUIRED
                   --> preflight_required = false
t=8075 [st=  0]   +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=851]
                   --> priority = "HIGHEST"
                   --> traffic_annotation = 63171670
                   --> url = "https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv"
t=8075 [st=  0]      NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_URL_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=8075 [st=  0]      TRANSPORT_SECURITY_STATE_SHOULD_UPGRADE_TO_SSL
                     --> get_sts_state_result = true
                     --> host = "client.app.net"
                     --> host_found_in_hsts_bypass_list = false
                     --> should_upgrade_to_ssl = true
t=8075 [st=  0]     +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=851]
                     --> initiator = "https://client.app.net"
                     --> load_flags = 131072 (CAN_USE_SHARED_DICTIONARY)
                     --> method = "GET"
                     --> network_isolation_key = "https://our.company.net https://our.company.net"
                     --> request_type = "subframe"
                     --> site_for_cookies = "SiteForCookies: {site=https://our.company.net; schemefully_same=true}"
                     --> url = "https://client.app.net/some/url/report.csv"
t=8075 [st=  0]        FIRST_PARTY_SETS_METADATA  [dt=0]
                       --> cache_filter = "none"
                       --> frame_entry = "none"
                       --> top_frame_primary = "none"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COMPUTED_PRIVACY_MODE
                       --> privacy_mode = "disabled"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "EXCLUDE_NOT_ON_PATH, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        COOKIE_INCLUSION_STATUS
                       --> operation = "send"
                       --> status = "INCLUDE, DO_NOT_WARN"
t=8075 [st=  0]        NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_START_TRANSACTION  [dt=0]
t=8076 [st=  1]        HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=8076 [st=  1]        HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_OR_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                       --> result = "created"
t=8076 [st=  1]        HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=8076 [st=  1]       +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=546]
t=8076 [st=  1]          HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                         --> source_dependency = 947 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=8622 [st=547]          HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                         --> source_dependency = 949 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=8622 [st=547]       -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=8622 [st=547]       +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_CONNECTED  [dt=0]
t=8622 [st=547]          PRIVATE_NETWORK_ACCESS_CHECK
                         --> client_address_space = "public"
                         --> resource_address_space = "public"
                         --> result = "allowed-potentially-trustworthy-same-origin"
t=8622 [st=547]       -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_CONNECTED
t=8622 [st=547]       +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=8622 [st=547]          HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                         --> GET /some/url/report.csv HTTP/1.1
                             Host: client.app.net
                             Connection: keep-alive
                             sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"
                             sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
                             sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
                             Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
                             User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
                             Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
                             Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
                             Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
                             Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
                             Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
                             Referer: https://client.app.net/
                             Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                             Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8
                             Cookie: [506 bytes were stripped]
t=8622 [st=547]       -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=8622 [st=547]       +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=303]
t=8622 [st=547]          HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=303]
t=8925 [st=850]          HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                         --> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                             Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                             X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
                             Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
                             Cache-Control: max-age=86400
                             Expires: Wed, 13 Dec 2023 09:02:47 GMT
                             Pragma: cache
                             Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.csv"; filename*=utf-8''report.csv
                             Content-Length: 1834
                             X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
                             X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                             X-Robots-Tag: none
                             Referrer-Policy: strict-origin
                             Permissions-Policy: geolocation=(), midi=(), sync-xhr=(self), microphone=(), camera=(), magnetometer=(), gyroscope=(), fullscreen=(), payment=()
t=8925 [st=850]       -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=8925 [st=850]        HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_INFO  [dt=1]
t=8926 [st=851]        HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_DATA  [dt=0]
t=8926 [st=851]        NETWORK_DELEGATE_HEADERS_RECEIVED  [dt=0]
t=8926 [st=851]     -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
t=8926 [st=851]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_RESPONSE_STARTED  [dt=0]
t=8926 [st=851]      HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=8926 [st=851]      URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                     --> byte_count = 1834
t=8926 [st=851]      HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=8926 [st=851] -CORS_REQUEST
t=8926 [st=851] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

So, can someone indicates me what is the difference here? What could cause the CANCELLED event?

Also I noticed the Chrome versions are different but I don't believe it is the cause. At first I thought it's because of CORS but then I realized it's indeed the same site, and it's GET, and `preflight_required` is `false`. So I guess it's not due to CORS.

Front-end uses Vaddin.